# Contracts work on testrpc but not Rinkeby. Using delegatecall (upgradeable contracts) pattern and trying to add new Contract() to array is failing

Tags: solidity, truffle, rinkeby, delegatecall, inheritance

I have a series of contracts that work perfectly fine on testrpc but not when I deploy to Rinkeby. I am using a standard token contract with Zeppelin that I am having no issues with.

The issue is with the registry contract. I have a `BaseRegistry` contract that is from https://regis.nu/. I can show it here but I think what's important is that my child contract is inheriting from the `BaseContract`. Here is the `ChildRegistry`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import "./BaseRegistry.sol";
import "../token/Token.sol";
import "../node/Node.sol";


contract ChildRegistry is BaseRegistry {

address public owner;
address public nodeDelegateAddress;
address[] public registeredNodes;

address public delegateContract;
address[] public previousDelegates;
uint256 public count;
address public tokenAddress;

  event DelegateChanged(address oldAddress, address newAddress);

  function ChildRegistry() {
    // constructor
  }

  function changeDelegate(address _newDelegate) returns (bool) {
    /*assert(owner == msg.sender);*/

    if (_newDelegate != delegateContract) {
        previousDelegates.push(delegateContract);
        var oldDelegate = delegateContract;
        delegateContract = _newDelegate;
        DelegateChanged(oldDelegate, _newDelegate);
        return true;
      }
    return false;

}

  function registerNode() {
    delegateContract.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("registerNode()")));
  }

  function createNodeContract () {
    delegateContract.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("createNodeContract()")));
  }

  function getNodes() constant returns (address[]) {
    return registeredNodes;
  }

  function setTokenAddress(address _tokenAddress) {
    delegateContract.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("setTokenAddress(address)")), _tokenAddress);
  }
  function setNodeDelegateAddress(address _nodeDelegateAddress) {
    delegateContract.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("setNodeDelegateAddress(address)")), _nodeDelegateAddress);
  }


}
```

The `ChildRegistry` is calling the delegate contract and updating its own state once it's set:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import "./BaseRegistry.sol";
import "../token/Token.sol";
import "../node/Node.sol";


contract ChildRegistryDelegate is BaseRegistry {

address public owner;
address public nodeDelegateAddress;
address[] public registeredNodes;

address public delegateContract;
address[] public previousDelegates;
uint256 public count;
address public tokenAddress;

  function ChildRegistryDelegate() {
    // constructor
  }


  function registerNode() {

    count += 1;

    Token existingToken = Token(tokenAddress);
    token.burn(1,msg.sender);
    register(msg.sender, "string");      
  //tokenAddress.call(bytes4(sha3("burn(uint256,address)")),1,msg.sender);

    createNodeContract();
  }

  function createNodeContract () {

    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.changeDelegate(nodeDelegateAddress);
    newNode.setOwner(msg.sender);
    newNode.setTokenAddress(tokenAddress);
    registeredNodes.push(newNode);

    /*newNode.call(bytes4(sha3("changeDelegate(address)")), nodeDelegateAddress);
    newNode.call(bytes4(sha3("setOwner(address)")), msg.sender);
    newNode.call(bytes4(sha3("changeDelegate(address)")), tokenAddress);*/

    registeredNodes.push(newNode);
  }

  function getNodes() constant returns (address[]) {
    return registeredNodes;
  }

  function setTokenAddress(address _tokenAddress) {
    tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
  }

  function setNodeDelegateAddress(address _nodeDelegateAddress) {
    assert(owner == msg.sender);
    nodeDelegateAddress = _nodeDelegateAddress;
  }

}
```

When I deploy the contracts I set the proper delegates manually. I know the `delegatecall` works because I can `setTokenAddress` and `setNodeDelegateAddress` perfectly fine. The issue is when I `registerNode`. On testrpc, it works fine. When I deploy to Rinkeby, nothing works. Nothing gets added to `registeredNodes`, `register` does not get called, and the `token.burn` does not work.

I added the `count` to see the the `delegatecall` would work then, and it does. The burn also works when I comment everything out and add `tokenAddress.call(bytes4(sha3("burn(uint256,address)")),1,msg.sender);`.

When I call `createNodeContract`, nothing works either. When I comment all the function calls and just try `Node newNode = new Node();` and `registeredNodes.push(newNode);` nothing happens.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I have a feeling it has to do with the `BaseRegistry` contract and how it's inheriting. I also think it might be how I am deploying my contracts with truffle. Here is my `2_deploy_contracts.js`:

```
var Token = artifacts.require('./Token.sol')
var ChildRegistry = artifacts.require('./ChildRegistry.sol')
var ChildRegistryDelegate = artifacts.require('./ChildRegistryDelegate.sol')
var NodeDelegate = artifacts.require('./NodeDelegate.sol')

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Token);
  deployer.deploy(ChildRegistry);
  deployer.deploy(ChildRegistryDelegate);
  deployer.deploy(NodeDelegate);
};
```

I also thought it may have to do with how I'm deploying them. I have no idea. Anything would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the transaction on Rinkeby? Is it reverting or not?

Comment: It's going through just fine, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Geth console was not reading my `truffle.js` file for some reason. Looks like this:

```
rinkeby: {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 8545,
  network_id: "4",
  from: "0xfc7846d06fab273c62cda0d29eac0936a22eeca4",
  gas: 2000000
}
```

Still isn't reading it. Everything works, but the transactions were running out of gas and failing. Have to add the gas manually `{from:sender, gas:2000000}` in each transaction for them to work.